# Importing "Libraries" from old laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, windows-libraries

This is a follow-up question to one I asked a few days ago.

I'm trying to transfer data from my old laptop (which won't turn on) to a new one. I have a 2.5" SATA hard drive enclosure so I can move data from my old drive to my new one fairly easily. However, there's a lot of stuff (documents, music, etc.) that I had saved in the "Libraries" section of my PC, which I can't find on my drive. Am I just making a silly mistake or do I need to do something else to transfer this other material?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7, and referring to the libraries Documents, Music, Pictures, Video?

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry, I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 7 libraries are a special "union" view of multiple folders. By default, they are a combination of

```
C:\Users\<your user>\Documents
```

and

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents
```

(repeat for `Pictures`, `Music`, and `Video` folders)

If you can't find the files in your personal folders, check the same folders in the `Public` user profile.